# How am i able to display my toast results in textview on another activity

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-toast

I have just started on android studio and i am creating a app that allows users to select the food they want and displaying the ordered food.

I am now trying to display the results i have in my toast to another activity.
The results is from a listview .I am able to get the results from toast on menuactivity but is there anyway to display it as textview on another activity ? Below are my codes.

customadapter

```
public class CustomLVAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<CustomItem> objectList;
    private int[] imageId;
    public static ArrayList<CustomItem> arl_food=new ArrayList<>();

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt1,txt2,txt3;
        CheckBox ckBox;
        ImageView image;    
        NumberPicker np;
    }

    public CustomLVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomItem> objectList,int[]prgmImages){
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objectList = objectList;
        this.imageId = prgmImages;

        this.objectList=objectList;
        arl_food.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<this.objectList.size();i++) {
            arl_food.add(this.objectList.get(i));
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return objectList.size();
    }

    public CustomItem getItem (int position) {
        return objectList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checkbox_textview, null);
            holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            holder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            holder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
            holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.ckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ckBox);
            holder.np  = (NumberPicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            holder.np.setMinValue(0);
            holder.np.setMaxValue(10);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.ckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    CustomItem object = (CustomItem) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(context,"You have selected:  " + object.getItem() + 
                        "Price: " + object.getPrice() + 
                        "Qty: " + object.getQty(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    object.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    arl_food.get(position).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });

            holder.np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                    NumberPicker p = picker;
                    CustomItem object = (CustomItem) p.getTag();
                    object.setQty(String.valueOf(newVal));
                    arl_food.get(position).setQty(String.valueOf(newVal));
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        CustomItem object = objectList.get(position);
        holder.txt1.setText(object.getItem());
        holder.txt2.setText(object.getDesc());
        holder.txt3.setText(object.getPrice());

        holder.np.setTag(object);
        holder.image.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder.ckBox.setChecked(object.isSelected());
        holder.ckBox.setTag(object);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

menu activity

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    private String server = "http://172.16.156.56";
    private String sql_table = "orders";
    private ListView list;
    private TextView txtOrder, txtMember, txtPrice;
    private Button btnAdd;
    ArrayList<String> rows;

    ListView listView1;
    Button btnSubmit;
    ArrayList<CustomItem> itemList, selectedList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        final String strOrder = txtOrder.getText().toString();
        final String strMember = txtMember.getText().toString();
        final String strPrice = txtPrice.getText().toString();

        txtOrder=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txtMember=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txtPrice=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);

        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        rows = new ArrayList<String>();

        itemList=new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Fried Rice","description","1","Quantity"));
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Fried Noodle","description","2","Quantity"));
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Prawn noodle","description","3","Quantity"));
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Chicken Rice","description","4","Quantity"));

        int[] prgmImages={R.drawable.friedrice,R.drawable.friednoodle,R.drawable.pnoodle,R.drawable.chickenrice};

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final CustomLVAdapter customLVAdapter = new CustomLVAdapter(this, itemList,prgmImages);
        listView1.setAdapter(customLVAdapter);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                selectedList = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
                int total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
                    CustomItem object = itemList.get(i);
                    if (object.isSelected()) {
                        responseText.append(object.getItem() + "," + object.getQty() + ",");//item
                        selectedList.add(object);
                        //calculate price
                        total = total + Integer.parseInt(object.getQty()) * Integer.parseInt(object.getPrice());

                    }
                }
                Add(responseText.toString(), "5565", String.valueOf(total));

                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReceiptActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Order", strOrder);
                i.putExtra("Member", strMember);
                i.putExtra("Price", strPrice);
                startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText + " $" + total,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                SelectAll();
                //store in database

                //go to ReceiptActivity - membership, item, totalprice

            }
        });
    }

    public void Add(final String item, final String membership, final String price)
    {
        RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = server + "/insertorder.php";
        StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                MyData.put("item",item );
                MyData.put("membership",membership );
                MyData.put("price",price );

                return MyData;
            }
        };
        MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
        SelectAll();
    }
    public void SelectAll()
    {
        RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = server + "/fetchorder.php";
        StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(sql_table);
                    rows.clear();
                    for(int i=0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                        String order       = jsonChildNode.optString("item").toString();
                        String membership     = jsonChildNode.optString("membership").toString();
                        String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price").toString();

                        rows.add(order + ", " + membership + ", " + price );
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rows);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //This code is executed if there is an error.
            }
        });
        MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
    }
}
```

Receipt activity (the page results should be displayed on)

```
public class ReceiptActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String strOrder = extras.getString("Order");
        String strMember = extras.getString("Member");
        String strPrice = extras.getString("Price");

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Order:" +strOrder+" ");   

        for(int i=0;i<CustomLVAdapter.arl_food.size();i++)
        {
            if(CustomLVAdapter.arl_food.get(i).isSelected())
            {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText("Food ordered: " );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Customitem

```
public class CustomItem {
    private  int id;
    private  String item;
    private  String price;
    private  String desc;
    private String qty;
    private  Boolean selected = false;

    public CustomItem(){    
    }

    public CustomItem(String item,String desc, String price,String qty){
        this.item=item;
        this.desc=desc ;
        this.price=price;
        this.qty=qty;
    }

    public CustomItem(int id, String item,String desc, String price,String qty){
        this.id=id;
        this.item=item;
        this.desc=desc;
        this.price=price;
        this.qty=qty;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (int id) {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public String getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item){
        this.item=item;
    }


    public String getDesc()
    {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc=desc;
    }

    public String getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price=price;
    }

    public String getQty()
    {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty=qty;
    }    

    public boolean isSelected(){
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){
        this.selected=selected;
    }
}
```

Checkbox listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView1"
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    style="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView2"
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView3"
    android:id="@+id/txt3"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt2" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ckBox"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt3"
    />

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ckBox"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ckBox" />
```

Comment: Use `Intent` to pass the selected item to the next `Activity`.

Comment: Intents was designed fort that kind of action. Check: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html